STM32 not starting when input voltage not dropping to zero
I am facing start-up issues during power on for the STM32L433.
When voltage comes from zero everything works fine. But, if I disconnect the power supply from the wall socket and its internal capacitors are not fully discharged and reconnect, the STM32 does not start. In this case the reset pin is inactive, not responding to a manual reset!
The board operates in 3V3. The reset pin has an external 39k pull resistor (also tested with 10k) and a 100nF capacitor.
Changing the BOR setting to level 4 seams to improve a bit. But, still not solving the problem.
There is a note about it in the documentation:
Beware that for proper start-up, the supply voltage must drop to 0 V before it can be reconnected, otherwise proper power-on reset may not be guaranteed.
This situation might occur in the field, it is commum to have a short time power fail. End the voltage will not drop to zero.
What can be done to improve the Hardware or Software to avoid this situation?

What board is this? and what documentation that you're referring to? This doesn't seems to be a software related question, so it is off-topic on Stack Overflow, and you might get better answer from electronics.stackexchange.com.

It is a custom board. As some of the power supply/reset settings are done via Software, like BOR levels, I do not think it is off-topic. Maybe I am missing something in these settings. I found the note in the ST Community, see link bellow: https://community.st.com/t5/stm32-mcus/why-my-stm32-doesn-t-start/ta-p/49367#:~:text=Power%20supply,Vdd%20and%20Vdda%20supply%20pins.

As indicated, I replicated my question here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/713695/stm32-not-starting-when-input-voltage-not-dropping-to-zero
